# A lot of incorrect JavaScript errors in the ASP.NET Core Template Pack for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I found the [ASPNETCoreTemplatePack by MadsKristensen](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack) a very good starting point for developing ASP.NET Core applications using Angular 2 as frontend. But as I started editing, I got **448** errors in the error-list dialog. Some of them are from the example Angular components, others actually generated by node.js modules. All came from TypeScript files. The *project* column says *virtual TypeScript project* and I opened some at random.

**Example**

Nr. 1: `ClientApp/app/components/app/counter/counter.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'counter',
    template: require('./counter.component.html')
})
```

Here VS says *The name "require" was not found*.

Nr 2: `node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/map.d.ts`

```
import { MapSignature } from '../../operator/map';
declare module '../../Observable' {
    interface Observable<T> {
        map: MapSignature<T>;
    }
}
```

Error: *Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found.*

And so on, as I said there are nearly 500 of them. Seems that Visual Studio misunderstand something here, as the app is compiling and all function work like expected. Also the counter-component, which couldn't work when the error was true, cause the require-function load its view. So I want to disable those errors - they make me missing *real* errors in my code, which had to be fixed.

**Things I already tried:**

- Setting `TypeScriptCompileBlocked` to true in the project file like described here: http://rostacik.net/2015/08/14/how-to-disable-building-of-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-2015/
- Added a `tsconfig.json` in the project-root with `"exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ]`

Answer (score 0):

By doing some research I found out that the used functions like `module` or `require` and also some syntax-constructs are introcuted in the TypeScript 2.0 Version. First this was confusing me, since my `package.json`file already refers to TypeScript in the 2.0.0 Version. Also an upgrade to 2.1.5 (latest version in time of writing) doesn't change anything.

After trying some other things I searched for the needle in the haystack as we said in Germany. And I learned that Visual Studio has a [TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=48593) package. This seems to contain some sort of rules to validate TypeScript in the errorlist-window. Its version is the same as TypeScript: TypeScript 2.1.5 > TypeScript for Visual Studio (2015) 2.1.5.

So its **very important** to have the same version of *TypeScript for Visual Studio* installed as the TypeScript version you're using as compiler. In my case, I had TypeScript for Visual Studio in Version 1.8.36 since I'm new to it and never used it before. Seems like the default one installed by VS. But the  ASPNETCoreTemplatePack refers to 2.0.0 which caused this problem.

## Install a specific version

My solution above will cause a new problem. The download page from Microsoft lists multiple older versions like 2.1.4 or 2.0.6 with links for downloading. But all refers to *TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe*, which is the latest (so currently 2.1.5). You could get a wider range of versions in the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=typescript%20for%20visual%20studio&target=VS&sortBy=Relevance).

**Please note:** Some versions of the market contains warnings that installing the addon would break their VS or TypeScript. I don't had tried this, since the latest version 2.1.5 is fine for me. But its may a good hint for people who had problems with the latest version. Please take care, backup your data and better create some sort of restore point, so that you can easily get a working development-area in case of anything breaks.